# How do I print directly to the port and ip using Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, printing, ip

I have a printer with network card and the door of communication. How do I print directly to the port and ip using Delphi 2010?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think that's possible without installing printer drivers, unless you want to write your own drivers.

Comment: ShellExecute (0, 'printto', PChar (DocNome), PChar (192.168.2.1:5044), nil, SW_HIDE);

Comment: If I use the above code will work?

Comment: It depends what "door of communication" your printer have **exactly**. Is it JetDirect? Or [LPD](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1179)? Please be specific and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: No, your ShellExecute will not work. It does not print directly to the printer; it tells the application associated with whatever is in `DocNome` to launch and print the document. That's not what your question asks.

Comment: Technically, that code won't even compile.

Comment: Open port 9100 and send the bytes.  If it's LPR/LPD its a bit more complex. Odds are it supports RAW through 9100.

Comment: You need to send information to the ip/port of the printer that the printer understands, and that results in it printing what you want to print. A gargantuan task if you start from scratch. Start by reading the documentation and specification for your printer. Then, when you understand what you are asking, do it through the driver!

Comment: Something like "Printer.BeginDoc" does not work. From what I understand, it may be possible with socket. If so, how? Do you have a code example in delphi using raw? How do I send the file to the ip / port of the printer?

Comment: @user3763613 Sending over IP is the same, no matter what's at the other end. What are you going to send? Did you read the documentation yet? Or are we expected to do that for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the documentation. Just gave me the IP address and port.

Comment: How do you propose to do this? Do you know what printer drivers are?

Comment: The printer is a host on the network. The sending of document must be through the ip and port. If the driver was installed locally would be very simple. I would select the printer from the list of local printers or send to the default printer. For example: 

begin
  Printer.Orientation := poPortrait; 
  Printer.BeginDoc;
  Printer.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect,Image.Picture.Graphic);
  Printer.EndDoc;
end;

But based on the ip and port I do not know how to do. This is the problem I'm asking. Anyway, if these data are not sufficient to answer, I appreciate the attempt to help me. Thanks.